# C Sharp : Arguments to pass in ado.net recordset

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to execute a codeline similar to the following

```
rs3 = cn2.Execute(strsql);
```

but i guess in c# i have to pass some arguments ato exceute the strsql. Can someone enlighten me on this topic.

Thankyou

Comment: Are you really using ADODB instead of ADO.NET?  ADODB is not supported on the .NET environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have a look at the classes & interfaces that ADO.NET provides to you:

IDbConnection, ICommand, SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc....
Have a look in the System.Data namespace.

For instance:

```
// setup a connection to a sql server
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( "here is the connectionstring" );

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conn);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = @pId";
cmd.Parameters.Add ("@pId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;

using( SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ADO.NET Command Object](http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/howto/doc/adoplus/ExecuteCommand.aspx)